# Use the default implementation of an interface if nothing passed as function parameter

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I have an interface with default implementation:

```
  interface MyInterface {
        fun foo() = "foo"
        fun bar() = 120        
    }
```

So I am trying to create a function that would expect as a parameter a `MyInterface` or use the default implementation if one is not passed.
The following does not compile:
`fun(param1: String, param2: Int, myInterface: MyInteface = MyInterface())`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that implements the interface, and use

```
class MyDefaultImplementation : MyInterface

fun(param1: String, param2: Int, myInterface: MyInterface = MyDefaultImplementation())
```

Or even better, create an object (singleton) that implements this interface, and use that object as default value.

```
object MyDefaultImplementationObject : MyInterface
fun(param1: String, param2: Int, myInterface: MyInterface = MyDefaultImplementationObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

The default then needs to be an object which implements the interface...

```
class MyInterfaceImplementation: MyInterface

fun (param1: String, param2: Int, myInterface: MyInteface = MyInterfaceImplementation()) {
    /* Function implementation */
}
```

Comment: This does not compile. I get a `this class does not have a constructor` for `MyInterface()`

Comment: Sorry @Jim you'll rather have to create a class that implements the interface and then use that as the default object

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, you need an object which implements your interface.

Perhaps the simplest way of creating one is using the `object : <ClassOrInterface>` syntax:

```
fun myFun(param1: String, param2: Int, myInterface: MyInterface = object : MyInterface{}) {
    // …
}
```

That may create a new object for each call which uses the default*.  If that matters, you might want to create an object separately:

```
val defaultImpl = object : MyInterface

fun myFun(param1: String, param2: Int, myInterface: MyInterface = defaultImpl) {
    // …
}
```

<sup>(* Kotlin 1.3.50 always seems to create a new instance each time the default is used.  But that behaviour isn't specified in the docs, so it could potentially be optimised in future releases.)</sup>